# ios how to send json data with http post request

Tags: ios, json, http-post, afnetworking

Here is the code i try to do, it returns unauthorized

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
 [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user": @"name",@"email": @"a@gmail.com"};

[manager POST:@"http://testgcride.com:8081/v1/users" parameters:parameters 

success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: I'm guessing the testgcride API you're calling requires some sort of authorization header to be sent with the request?

Answer (score 0):

[The URL you're using](http://testgcride.com:8081/v1/users) requires a username and password to access.

It looks like it's HTTP Basic Authentication, so you should be able to obtain the credentials and set them:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
```